# How to subset a dataframe with an vector of critera for the dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset

Suppose I have a dataframe that I want to filter out certain elements, in this case I want to only filter out specific colleges from the dataframe. 
The column I am filtering by is called "OWNER" and I want to filter out several schools such as "DUKE", "COLUMBIA", "STANFORD" etc.

If I make an vector of the names of schools, how can I use the vector to filter out the specific schools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `subset` with `%in%`

```
v1 <- c("DUKE", "COLUMBIA", "STANFORD")
df2 <- subset(df1, OWNER %in% v1 )
```

If we need to remove those schools, negate (`!`)

```
df2 <- subset(df1, !OWNER %in% v1 )
```

---

With `dplyr`, we can use `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
          filter(OWNER %in% v1)
```